# Photoelectric effect - electric potential

Tags: photoelectric-effect

[image]

[image]

Can someone explain why the potential of the copper sphere is equal to the kinetic energy of the electron released/ electric charge?

I understand that the energy of the photon is transferred to the electron. So the work function energy is used to increase the potential energy of the electron (pull it out of its potential well) and any excess energy of that photon that was transferred becomes the electron’s kinetic energy. Where does that electric potential energy between the electron and copper sphere come from? Why is it maximum when kinetic energy is maximum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that you had a machine which projected balls of mass $m$ with a range of speeds vertically.
As the balls rose their speed would decrease with their kinetic energy $\frac 12 mv^2$ being converted into gravitational potential energy.
The speed of a ball becomes zero when it reaches its maximum height, $h$ and it has the largest gravitational potential energy $mgh_{\rm fastest}$, relative to that at the surface of the Earth.
The balls which are emitted the fastest, $v_{\rm fastest}$, are the ones which rise the highest, $h_{\rm fastest}$, and have the largest initial kinetic energy.

In the photoelectric effect the electrons are emitted with a range of kinetic energies yup to a maximum value.
Those photoelectrons which the largest kinetic energy are the ones that have not lost energy in their passage to the surface of the conductor and then escaping.
Take the zero of electric potential energy of the charged sphere as zero.

As the electrons leave the surface of the conducting sphere the lose kinetic energy and gain electric potential energy, $eV$ where $V$ is the potential difference between the position of the electron and the surface of the sphere.
Those electrons with the highest kinetic energy rise the most and are the greatest distance from the charged sphere.